# Enable Windows Office Features (OneNote Office Standard 2013)

Tags: powershell, deployment, ms-office

Been researching this for a bit and haven't found a good solution. Some users use OneNote but most don't even have it installed. We are looking for a way to enable OneNote and install on all of our machines (thinking powershell or msi file). We have a managed installations distributor that we would like to use (KACE SMA). I can't seem to find a working msi or script to enable OneNote for Office Standard 2013. Has anyone gotten this to work/any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried both these methods with no luck: (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2014/05/14/step-by-step-customizing-an-office-2013-installation/) and (https://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/79-create-an-office-2013,-2016-and-365-offline-installer-with-the-office-deployment-tool)

Answer (score 0):

I think OneNote is available as a standalone install for free now.

Check https://www.onenote.com/Download

There is a 'Windows Desktop' download. If you run the installer with the /? argument you will be presented with the following options:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Downloads> .\setuponenotefreeretail.x86.en-us_.exe /?
PS C:\Users\User\Downloads>
Office Deployment Tool

SETUP [mode] [path]

SETUP /download [path to configuration file]
SETUP /configure [path to configuration file]
SETUP /packager [path to configuration file] [output path]
SETUP /customize [path to configuration file]
SETUP /help

 /download Downloads files to create an Office installation source
 /configure Adds, removes, or configures an Office installation
 /packager Produces an Office App-V package from an Office installation source
 /customize Applies settings for Office applications
 /help Displays this message
```

So I guess you will need to present it with a configuration file similar to the one you use for the click-to-run installer for Office.

Check if this version does what you need it to do and then try to find a configuration file online if you want to deploy it automatically.

I hope this helps.